# Can I tell if a device has an active Activation Lock before inserting a SIM card?

Tags: iphone, icloud, ios, activation-lock

I got an iPhone 5c off of eBay and I can't tell if it's iCloud locked (Activation Lock) or not because I don't have a SIM card for it yet. It was restored by iTunes with no problems. The phone asks me for my language, country, WiFi, then tells me to insert a SIM. Is it going to tell me I need the previous owners password after I get the SIM card and insert it?

Comment: is the WiFi working? if yes use it to access iCloud.

Comment: @Buscar Could you expand what you mean? OP does not have a SIM card to 'access iCloud'…?

Answer (score 1):

*If you are referring to "Find my iPhone" with "if it's icloud locked":*

No, "Find my iPhone" must be turned off on your new iPhone. iTunes doesn't let you restore an iDevice with turned on "Find my iPhone" (on iOS 7 and greater)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Apple has a very easy page that lets you look up devices by IMEI or Serial Number:

- https://www.icloud.com/activationlock/

[image]